# change the state of variables if 2 variables have same state

Tags: java

Hi im unsure my title explained my prob very well,

basically i have 2 variables : -

```
public int driverNumberOne;
public int driverNumberTwo;
```

firstly the user sets driverNumberOne to an int value, then driverNumberTwo to another int value, but what i want it to do, when the user inputs for example an int value for driverNumberTwo  i want the method to change the value of driverNumberOne to a different value so i dnt get 2 variable with same int value.
this is my basic method header and body so far, been spending ages trying to figure out what to do :-(

```
/**
 * Allows the user to change the number for driver one.
 */
public void setDriverNumberTwo(int aDriverNumber)
{
   this.setDriverNumberTwo(aDriverNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you wrote leading to an infinite loop..

```
public void setDriverNumberTwo(int aDriverNumber ) {
    this.setDriverNumberTwo(aDriverNumber);// <- delete this line if you don't want an infinite loop method
    ...
}
```

The right way you can do what you want, is:

```
public void setDriverNumberTwo() {
    if (driverNumberOne == driverNumberTwo)
        driverNumberOne++;
}
```

Comment: nitpic - this isn't an infinite loop, it's recursion.  An infinite loop would never end whereas this will ultimate terminate with a StackOverflowError

Comment: It depends.. if compiler supports _tail recursion_ this will never end.. however, it doesn't matter.. What I want to say is that the code he wrote will never lead to the expected result..

Comment: all compilers support tail recursion, I believe you're thinking of tail recursion optimisation.  The original point still stands no matter what- this isn't an infinite loop, it's recursion

Answer (score -1):

```
public int driverNumberOne; 
public int driverNumberTwo;
public void setDriverNumberTwo(int aDriverNumber) {
    this.setDriverNumberTwo(aDriverNumber);
    if (this.driverNumberOne == this.driverNumberTwo) {
        ... change the value of the second variable to whatever ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This code, like the OPs code will lead to a stack overflow error

Answer (score -1):

```
public void setDriverNumberTwo(int aDriverNumber )
{
    this.setDriverNumberTwo(aDriverNumber);
    if (this.driverNumberOne == this.driverNumberTwo) {
        // Set this.driverNumberOne to any Random Number 
    }
}
```

Comment: This would give you infinite recursion, though that was true in the original code too.